# ISP Bonding with outgoing VPN and QOS - hardware, software?

Tags: vpn, bonding

My company has an office that is... at the end of a slow cable balsed link (6mbit / 0,5mbit up) with no real chance to get it faster (outskirts of the city, we tried). We may have an ugprade coming in half a year... but until then we can have 2-3 f the same link.

Now, I am looking for a solution that allows me to:

- Bond these links for outgoing traffic (web requests etc.) preferably with QOS
- Bond a VPN from this office to the central server cluster in a data center. The other side is a 2008 R2 RRAS server currently on PPTP, but any other thing is OK. I would prefer not to have to put some hardware router in there for various reasons, one  being cost.
- Perfect would be if the solution could do QOS over the VPN link so I can prioritize SIP traffic and other real tim / close to real time stuff (remote desktops).

Anyone any solution / recommendation? I can deal with not too expensive hardware (as the benefit is not really worth that much to us) and / or a software appliance (getting some low power multi NIC dedicated machine).

Any ideas? So far I am looking into ZeroShell and / or possibly a hardware like from Draytek. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at MLPPP.